# Using powershell with 7zip - password protect each file in a folder

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I am trying to password protect 10 files (using the same password) in a folder.  Once completed, i would like to have 10 individual zip files each with the same password.  My script is as follows but it errors out saying it cant open the file as archive.

```
$list=gci "C:\temp\test"
foreach ($file in $list)
{
   $file1=$file|select -ExpandProperty name
   & 'c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe' a $file1.zip $file1 -p123
}
```

This is the error i get:

```
Open archive: testfile.pdf
7z.exe : ERROR: testfile.pdf
At line:6 char:5
+     & 'c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe' a $file1.zip $file1 -p123
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: testfile.pdf:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
Can not open the file as archive
System ERROR:
Incorrect function.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy...figured it out myself..needed quotation marks!!!

```
    & 'c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe' a "$file1.zip" $file1 -p123
```

Comment: Mark it as an answer @kahoots.